# How to change bootstrap button style by use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-block btn-warning" type="button" id="999">&nbsp;</a>
```

Button styled http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons

I want to change the style such as "btn-danger" or "btn-info" by use jQuery...I think need to remove style and add new...

How to do it. Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@asdf_enel_hak answer will work for you but if want to remove multiple classes at once with jquery do as :

```
$("#999").removeClass("btn-warning btn-block").addClass("btn-info");
```

or want to add multiple classes at once then do :

```
$("#999").removeClass("btn-warning btn-block").addClass("btn-info btn-danger");
```

Read more on [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#999").removeClass("btn-warning").addClass("btn-info");
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you would need to use the functions addClass() and removeClass. But you would need to use an id for the button, so you won't interfer with other existing buttons.

```
<a id="myButton"class="btn btn-small btn-block btn-warning" type="button" id="999">&nbsp;</a>
```

And then, you call the functions.

```
$( "#myButton" ).removeClass( "btn-warning" );
$( "#myButton" ).addClass( "btn-danger" );
```

You can also make it just in one line:

```
$( "#myButton" ).removeClass( "btn-warning" ).addClass( "btn-danger" );
```

Check this JSFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1085/